# Rewriting urls with Htaccess like filename/param1/param2 etc etc

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm looking for a solution for the following situation. I'd like to covert the following url

```
www.example.com/filename.php?p1=1&p2=2 etc
```

to

```
www.exmaple.com/filename/1/2 etc
```

I managed to do this, with index.php, but I'd like to use other file aswell, not only the index. Is it possible? Here's my current code.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# add .php to access file, but don't redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(filename)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /$1.php?p1=$2&p2=$3 [L,QSA,NC]


ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

# display no errs to user
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
```

This works for the php removal. But if I add parameters after it, it gives me error 500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(filename)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?p1=$2&p2=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: if I try like this www.example.com/profile/u/a gives me 404 error.
the profile is the file's name and the u and a are the parameters

Comment: And what happend when you load: `www.example.com/profile.php?p1=u&p2=a `

Comment: Nope, still doesn't works. There might be something with the .php removal. It gives me 404 errors.

Comment: Most likely it is because of some rules conflict. Can you post your latest .htaccess in your question again.

Comment: Looked at your code. You didn't follow my anser correctly. I wrote: `Insert this rule just below RewriteEngine On line` But you have it after your first rule. Change the order as suggested.

Comment: For handling profile case rule needs to be: `RewriteRule ^(profile)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?p1=$2&p2=$3 [L,QSA,NC]` and it needs to be just below RewriteBase line.

Comment: Omg :D Thanks it work. is there any way to make it not to require all the parameters?

Comment: What do you mean by: `to make it not to require all the parameters` ?

Comment: Like so I can use it like www.exmaple.com/profile/user and the with 1 param

Comment: Have another RewriteRule for this: `RewriteRule ^(profile)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?p1=$2 [L,QSA,NC]`